# How close multiple holes can be drill in top double plate?

Tags: electrical, wiring, framing

Have to drill multiple holes in top plate for wiring. how close can be drilled
have total 4 14/2 wires to be run through hole.

hole size- 5/8  to 3/4.

thanks

Comment: Wait top double plate of what?  In a panel you may want to avoid that area as it could contain the main breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not critical. You need 2 holes. If you have the space: 3 inches apart. Feed 2 wires per hole. Keep holes 1.25in from edge of plate.